# Access to a TextBox arrary

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox

I have created 16 textboxes in the Form Designer and would like to access them using an array

So far I have done this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{       
    TextBox[] descrip2Arr;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        TextBox[] descripArr = { decrip1_Box, decrip2_Box, decrip3_Box, decrip4_Box,
                                  decrip5_Box, decrip6_Box, decrip7_Box, decrip8_Box,
                                  decrip9_Box, decrip10_Box,decrip11_Box,decrip12_Box,
                                  decrip13_Box,decrip14_Box,decrip15_Box,decrip16_Box};


        for (int i = 0; i < descrip2Arr.Length; i++) 
           descrip2Arr[i].Text = "Descrip 2 cod " + (i + 1).ToString();

    }
}
```

This seems to work ok. 
The problem is that when I try to access to some member of the array from another method the array is empty (null).
How can I create an array that contain all my Text Boxes and which can be accessed from any method?

Comment: In the constructor it looks like you are populating the array. Is the method that you are trying to access it from within this class?

Comment: This array is local to the Form1 class. If you want to access it from another class you need two things. Make the array public and give to the other class the correct Form1 instance. However this should be done differently using a method on the Form1 class that return what the other class requires

Comment: Delete the `TextBox[]` from the `TextBox[] descripArr = {.. `line and your are actually intitalizing the one you have declared earlier, not creating a new one.

Comment: _This seems to work ok_ how this works? `descrip2Arr` is empty and you must get null reference exception in first iterate. as others said just remove `TextBox[] descripArr` and instead use `descrip2Arr` directly

Comment: Can you trying placing the initialisation in line with the declaration at the top of the class? So just do

`TextBox[]  descrip2Arr = ...`

Comment: you need to make the array a filed (member variable) of the class

Comment: the array is local to the Fomr1 class and I just want to access inside its class (form1 class). Taw, when I delete `TextBox[]` from `TextBox[] descripArr = {..` it show me an error  "; expected"

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using lists

```
List<TextBox> myBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

        myBoxes.Add(textBox1);
        myBoxes.Add(textBox2);
        myBoxes.Add(textBox3);
        myBoxes.Add(textBox4);
        myBoxes.Add(textBox5);

        myBoxes[0].Text = "Something";
```